# PHP file not being called from javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, forms, cookies

I am trying to call a form and php filefrom a javascript function but it does not work.  It might have to do with the cookies, it does not call the "frmSubdeptChainDailyHL" form   and it does not call the "subdeptclass_reportHL.php" file, here is the code:

```
function submitClassChainDaily()
{
    var store = readCookie('storeAccess');
    var clss = readCookie('classAccess');
    var subdept = readCookie('subDeptAccess');
  var period = readCookie('period');
  if (period == null || period == '') {
    period = 'CUR';
  }
  document.frmClassChainDaily.period.value = period;

    var storePref = readCookie('storePref');


  if (storePref == null || storePref == '') {
    if (store == null || store == '') {
        storePref = 'ALL';

    } else {
        storePref = store;



    }
  }
    if ((storePref.length) > 3 && storePref != 'ALL100') {
        document.setStore.submit();
    } else {
    document.frmClassChainDaily.store.value = storePref;
    if (clss == null || clss == '') {
        clss = 'ALL';
    }
      document.frmClassChainDaily.clss.value = clss;
    if (subdept == null || subdept == '') {
        subdept = 'ALL';
    }
      document.frmClassChainDaily.subdept.value = subdept;

    ";

      if ($_REQUEST['storePref']=='099')
    {    
    echo "document.frmSubdeptChainDailyHL.submit();";
} else {
    echo "document.frmSubdeptChainDaily.submit();";
}   
 echo "


  }
}



Here is the form code:

if ($_REQUEST['storeCode'] == '099') {
        echo"
<li>
    <!--   SubDept Daily Sales - Chain -->
    <form name=\"frmSubdeptChainDailyHL\" action=\"subdeptclass_reportHL.php\">
        <input type=hidden value=\"\" name=\"store\">
        <input type=hidden value=\"\" name=\"subdept\">
        <input type=hidden value=\"\" name=\"clss\">
        <input type=hidden value=\"\" name=\"period\">
    </form>
      <a style=\"display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #000\" href=\"javascript: submitSubDeptChainDaily();\">
        <h3 class=\"longfield\">
            <img src=\"content/images/icons/US_dollar_icon.png\" alt=\"icon\" class=\"icon\"/>
            <span>Sales</span>
        </h3>
      </a>
      </li>
```

Comment: One is 'storePref' and the other is 'storeCode'. Is that correct?

Comment: oh yes, sorry they are both storePref, I forgot to change the 2nd one.

Comment: setstore also has to do with the cookie and permissions I believe, sorry even I am just modifying this code: <!--   Need to set store. -->
    <form name=\"setStore\" action=\"setStore.html\">
    </form>
    <!--   User does not have access to the report requested. -->
    <form name=\"notPermit\" action=\"notPermitted.html\">
    </form>

Answer (score 1):

You cant directly call to a php function from javascript. Make use of some ajax calls